# Does presence of Link local address mean the system support IPv6?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, ipv6

I am trying to implement `dual stack` for **IPv6** support in a **IPv4** system. I have configured a **DHCP server** which gives IPv4 and IPv6 address to the device.

My PC and the VM running on it gets both, IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. The embedded system I am working on needs the dhcpcd command to get IP address. I get the IPv4 and Link local address but NOT the IPv6 address given by server.

Does this mean 
1.my embedded system doesn't support IPv6 (even though Link Local address is given)???
2.There is a different command to get IPv6 apart from dhcpcd ?

Comment: There are multiple ways for a system to get a global IPv6 address. One is auto-configuration (SLAAC), one is auto-configuration with additional info over DHCP (stateless DHCPv6), one is giving addresses over DHCP (stateful DHCPv6) and of course there is manual static configuration. It might well be that your system supports IPv6 but not stateful DHCPv6. Try SLAAC first. You won't need a DHCPv6 server in that scenario, just a router that sends out information in Router Advertisements. (PS: I don't think this is the right place for this question, you might want to move it to Superuser)

Answer (score 0):

### 1.my embedded system doesn't support IPv6 (even though Link Local address is given)???

To check if IPv6 is available you can try:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "IPv6 is supported"
```

But getting a link-local address shows you also that IPv6 is supported.

If you want to test whether the SLAAC/auto-configuration is enabled execute:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<interface>.autoconf
```

### 2.There is a different command to get IPv6 apart from dhcpcd ?

I only know the ISC "dhclient" as a DHCP client. I think this tool you can only either ask for an IPv4 or an IPv6 address. So try the argument "-6" on your DHCP client.